Split and paste columns as soon as value changes
For a new project, I have a large data set, containing 9000+ rows in column I-L as shown in the figure. As soon as the value (default 4.13) of column >5, I want the columns I-L to be split at that row and pasted into another column. There should be no changes if the value of column J lowers to 4.13 again. However, once it exceeds the value of 5 again (in this case 5.13), it should split the columns until it happens again. If the value exceeds 5, a new cycle starts.
In the figure, I only showed four sets of columns, but they should proceed until all >5 values in column J are processed.

In short: Column I-L is what I currently have and I want to split these into sets of columns.
Why I need it: My data results in very large graphs in series. My final goal is to present my dataset to be shown in parallel instead of series, to make comparison easier.

The code to split my columns is still very very poor and does not work at all.
Sub SplitColumns()

    'Declare variables
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Long
      
    ' Set number of rows of data
    NumRows = Range("J1", Range("J1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Debug.Print NumRows

    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    r = 1
    c = 12
    x = 2
    For x = 2 To NumRows - 2

    If Range("J" & x).Value > 4.13 Then
    Range("I, K, L" & x).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c))
        r = r + 1
    End If
    Next x

End Sub

Additional information: This data was gathered from a csv file generated by an external device. This is my only sheet. The values in column J are generally only two values and will not become negative. The value 4.13 means the system is closed, 5.13 means it is open. The values can slightly differ, but will  stay within 4-5 and 5-6, respectively.
The original columns I-L can be replaced by the new columns.
Thank you in advance.

Look into the WorkSheet.Change event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

A good question must be easily understood by people trying/wanting to help... So, you should try placing in our shoes and give us elements to clearly understand what you have and what you try doing. 1. How the data in discussion is changed? Are there formulas processing inputs from different sheets? In such a case you should use Worksheet_Calculate event. 2. Are the data changed or added directly on the respective columns? Manually (difficult to believe it...)? By an application using computer ports (USB, COM etc.)? If so, you should use Worksheet_Change.


I could not understood your intention to clarify starting with "This means, that every time the value of +-4.13 in column B". What do you really mean? When the event is needed to act in a direction or another one? If the existing value is 4,1 and it becomes -4.0 is it something to be done? Does the value increase/decrease continuously in small increments? Anyhow, supposing that you will clarify the action moment, do you want copying "A:A, C:D" range in a new column? How to copy them in a new column? Three columns starting from E:E? Then do you want it to continuously proceed in this way?


There are many other things to be clarified. For instance, should the chart be adapted for the next x added columns? Does the chart exist or it must also be build by the required code? I do not even understand what kind of such a chart do you need... Couldn't you find a standard type to show instead of manually building it? Who do you think must clarify such issues? What I tried emphasizing is the need to logically explain what you have against what you want! The VBA suggestions/solutions can come only after we clearly understand what you try doing. We hare are not mind readers...

Excuse me @FaneDuru. Thank you for your comment. I am still a bit searching on finding the easiest way to reach my goal. I rewrote my question and left the part about the graph out. Hopefully, it is somewhat easier to understand now.

I am driving now... I only hope that somebody else will be able to understand what you need...

You received two answers... Didn't you find some time to check them? If checked, didn't any of them do what you need?

This won't be fast but should do the job:
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, rng As Range, c As Range, v, vPrev
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet   'for example
    Set rng = ws.Range("I2:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row)
    Set c = ws.Range("O1") 'start pasting here
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vPrev = 99
    For Each rw In rng.Rows         'loop over data rows
        v = rw.Cells(2).Value       'col J
        If v > 5 And vPrev < 5 Then 'new data block?
            Set c = ws.Cells(1, c.Column + rw.Columns.Count) 'row 1 and 4 columns to right
        End If
        rw.Copy c            'copy row
        Set c = c.Offset(1)  'next paste position
        vPrev = v            'remember previous J value
    Next rw
End Sub


Please, test the next code, which should be very fast, even for large ranges. It places the range in an array and load a copy array with the processed result and drop its content at once, at the end:
Sub SplitCols()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrCopy, i As Long, j As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim prevVal As Single, maxGr As Long, groupNo As Long, maxiRow As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
    lastR = ws.Range("I" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on I:I column
    maxGr = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("J2:J" & lastR), ">5") 'to calculate maximum number of columns in arrCopy
    
    arr = ws.Range("I2:L" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
    ReDim arrCopy(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2) * maxGr) 'redim arrCopy at a maximum number of rows and columns
    
    prevVal = 6 'previous value to reset iRow when changed
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows
        If prevVal < 5 And arr(i, 2) > 5 Then iCol = iCol + 4: iRow = 0 'when to reinitialize array row and column!
        iRow = iRow + 1                       'increment the row of the present sequence
        If iRow > maxiRow Then maxiRow = iRow 'determine the maximum number of rows to be kept when drop the array content
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2): arrCopy(iRow, iCol + j) = arr(i, j): Next j 'write the row in the array to be copied
        prevVal = arr(i, 2) 'reinitialize previous value
    Next i
    
    
    'drop arrCopy content, at once, format the Time and AutoFit columns:
    Dim rngRet As Range: Set rngRet = ws.Range("O1").Resize(maxiRow, iCol + 4)
    With rngRet
        .Value2 = arrCopy
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit 'autofit returned columns
    End With
    Intersect(ws.Range(extractCols(rngRet, 4)).EntireColumn, rngRet).NumberFormat = _
                                                        "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
End Sub

Function extractCols(rng As Range, lngStep As Long) As String
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To rng.Columns.count Step lngStep
    extractCols = extractCols & "," & Split(rng.Columns(i).cells(1).address, "$")(1) & 1
  Next i
  extractCols = Mid(extractCols, 2)
End Function

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
The best result in terms of working fast is obtained avoiding using the Clipboard, avoiding selecting, activating, frequently copying row by row. The best result is obtained designing a piece of code able to work mostly in memory and drop the processing result at the end...
Anyhow, I feel the need to tell you working more to the question description (in words). Without the image I could never understand what you try doing, even after question update...
